# VHDL program doesn't set output

Tags: vhdl, fpga

This is my VHDL code:

```
entity Operation is
  port (
    clk16: in std_logic; // 16 MHz input clock
    start_cmd: inout std_logic; // open drain line. When CPLD sees it is pulled low, it keeps pulling it low till the operation is finished
    clk_out: buffer std_logic; // output clock derived from clk16
  );
end Operation;

architecture a of Operation is
  type T_STATE is (STOPPED, STARTING, ....another states....);
  signal state: T_STATE := STOPPED;

begin
  process (clk16, clk_out)
  begin

    if rising_edge(clk16) then
      clk_out <= not clk_out; -- create clk_out clock
    end if;

    if rising_edge(clk_out) then
       case state is
         when STOPPED =>
           if start_cmd = '0' then
             state <= STARTING;
             start_cmd <= '0' -- sometimes this doesn't happen
           end if;

         when STARTING =>
-- code continues here.... after the operation is finished, start_cmd <= 'Z' is "executed"
```

I have start_cmd signal connected to my CPLD. It is open drain signal with pull up that is connected also to another device. When another device wants CPLD to start some operation, it pulls start_cmd to low. When CPLD sees start_cmd is low it also pulls the line low. After a while another device releases the line. When the operation by CPLD is finished, CPLD releases the line. As nobody is now pulling the line low, the line goes high. Another device then knows that CPLD's operation finished.

The problem is that sometimes (10 %) start_cmd <= '0' is not "executed" so start_cmd signal returns high once another device stops pulling start_cmd low. Another device then detects false "operation finished".

Can you see any problem why start_cmd <= '0' is not "executed" sometimes?

I debugged my device using oscilloscope and I can see that this situation happens when another device pulls start_cmd to low exactly at rising edge of clk_out.

This VHDL is implemented on MAX V CPLD using Quartus Prime.

Answer (score 0):

First - I think you should always initialize the inout with 'Z' at start up

Add a new state INIT to T_STATE

`type T_STATE is (INIT,STOPPED, STARTING, ....another states....);`

and initialise state to INIT

`signal state: T_STATE := INIT;`

```
case state is
  when INIT =>
   start_cmd <= 'Z';
   state <= STOPPED;
  when STOPPED =>
  :
```

Second I'm not sure about the requirement of the clk_out buffer . I don't think it is needed unless there is a specific reason. It seems like all you need is

```
if falling_edge(clk16) then
    case state is
      :
```